# How to find $regex for integer value in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following collection.

```
[{
  _id: ObjectId("5b17ab5489264c2df61ed2d6"),
   amount: 12514545
}]
```

I want to search for `125` and get following document.

I have tried this but doesn't work:

```
db.collection.find({
  amount: {
    $regex: 125
  }
})
```

It would be better if it can be done through aggregate query.

```
  Test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "$or": [
    { "amount": { parseInt(searchString) }},
    { "firstName": { "$regex": searchString }}
  ] } }
  ])
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you want it?

Comment: @AlexBlex why so? Most people need these types of aggregation... Don't know what's you think so weird in the question...

Comment: @Ashish Just wondering what's the usecase. Couldn't imagine any good reason to search a number with "125" anywhere within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where) query operator to do non-standard queries like this, but it's not performant:

```
db.test.find({$where: 'this.amount.toString().match("125")'})
```

But you can't use `$where` in an aggregate `$match`.

To do this in aggregate, I think you'd have to maintain a separate string version of `amount` in each document that you use for regex searches.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5b17ab5489264c2df61ed2d6"),
   amount: 12514545,
   amountString: '12514545'
}
```

Then you could search it just as you would any other string field:

```
Test.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "$or": [
    { "amountString": { "$regex": searchString }},
    { "firstName": { "$regex": searchString }}
  ] } }
])
```

Comment: How to do that in aggregate query, Please see the updated question.

Comment: I want to use aggregate here in order to use $match, is there any way to handle this... @JohnnyHK